# Poisson equation in a cylinder

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions, poissons-equation, cylindrical-coordinates

I need to solve the problem $\nabla^{2} u(r,\theta,z)=Q(r,\theta,z)$
inside a circular cylinder $(0 < r < a, 0 < \theta < 2\pi, 0 < z < H)$ subject to $u = 0$ on the sides.

I'm supposed to use the eigenfunction method but I'm not very sure of how does it work in cylindrical cordinates. Does anyone know where can I find a good explanation of the method in cylindrical cordinates?

Thank you